# How to access oneToMany data with hibernate?. (Hibernate+Spring+Primefaces)

Tags: hibernate, primefaces

Hello I´m newbie with hibernate, I´m trying to access data without success :(. I´m trying it a month. I have two tables, the first Empresa and the second LDiario. I can see Empresa data, but when i select a radiobutton for access the next table (LDiario) i see it void.

OneToMany Empresa-->LDIario
ManyToOne LDIario-->Empresa

I ´m using Primefaces. Sorry by my english, I´m learning it.

**UPDATE** I have done update of LDiario, Empresa and i have added EmpresaBean

**EmpresaDaoImpl**

```
@Transactional
@Named
public class EmpresaDaoImpl implements EmpresaDao{

    @Inject
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Empresa> findAll() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Empresa").list();
    } 
}
```

**LDiarioImpl**

```
@Transactional
@Named
public class LDiarioDaoImpl implements LDiarioDao{

    @Inject
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<LDiario> findAll() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from LDiario").list();
    }
}
```

**Empresa** **UPDATE**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "empresas")
public class Empresa implements Serializable{

@Id 
@Column(name = "CLAVE")
@GeneratedValue private Integer CLAVE;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "empresa")
private List<LDiario> ldiarios;
```

**LDiario**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LDIARIO2014")
public class LDiario implements Serializable{

@Id 
@Column(name = "CLAVE")
@GeneratedValue private Integer CLAVE;  

@ManyToOne  
@JoinColumn (name = "empresa_id") 
private Empresa empresa;
```

**Empresa View (Primeface)** it works.

```
 <p:dataTable id="radioDT"  var="emp" value="#{empresaBean.getEmpresaList()}"  
                selection="#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa}" rowKey="#{emp.CLAVE}">



    <f:facet name="header">
            Lista de Empresas
         </f:facet>
         <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>         
      <p:column headerText="Id">
       <h:outputText value="#{emp.CLAVE}" />
       </p:column>

         <p:column headerText="Nombre Empresa">
       <h:outputText value="#{emp.NOMBRE}" />
       </p:column>

         <p:column headerText="AÑO">
       <h:outputText value="#{emp.EJERCICIO}" />
       </p:column>

       <!-- "#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa}" -->
<f:facet name="footer"
```

>
LDiario View (Not Works)

```
<p:dataTable   var="ld" value="#{empresaBean.ldiario}" rowKey="#{ld.CLAVE}">
        <!-- selection="#{ldiarioBean.selectedLdiario}" rowKey="#{ld.CLAVE}" -->

        <f:facet name="header">
            Listado Diario
         </f:facet>
         <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>         
      <p:column headerText="ASIENTO">
       <h:outputText value="#{ld.ASIENTO}" />
       </p:column>

         <p:column headerText="FECHA">
       <h:outputText value="#{ld.FECHA}" />
       </p:column>

         <p:column headerText="SUBCUENTA">
       <h:outputText value="#{ld.SUBCUENTA}" />
       </p:column>

           <p:column headerText="CONCEPTO">
       <h:outputText value="#{ld.CONCEPTO}" />
       </p:column>
```

I don´t know if the problem is EmpresaDaoService or another. I don´t know that write in this part.

**LDiario View**

```
<p:dataTable   var="ld" value="#{empresaBean.ldiario}" rowKey="#{ld.CLAVE}">
```

Thx very much.

**EmpresaBean**

```
@ManagedBean(name="empresaBean")
@ViewScoped
@Named
public class EmpresaBean {

    @Inject
    private EmpresaService empresaService;
    private Empresa empresa;
    private Empresa selectedEmpresa;
    private LDiario ldiario;




    public LDiario getLdiario() {
        return ldiario;
    }

    public void setLdiario(LDiario ldiario) {
        this.ldiario = ldiario;
    }

    public EmpresaService getEmpresaService() {
        return empresaService;
    }

    public Empresa getSelectedEmpresa() {
        return selectedEmpresa;
    }

    public void setSelectedEmpresa(Empresa selectedEmpresa) {
        this.selectedEmpresa = selectedEmpresa;
    }

    public void setEmpresaService(EmpresaService empresaService) {
        this.empresaService = empresaService;
    }

    public EmpresaBean(){
    }

    public List<Empresa> getEmpresaList(){

        return empresaService.getAll();
    }

    public Empresa getEmpresa() {
        return empresa;
    }
    public void setEmpresa(Empresa empresa) {
        this.empresa = empresa;
    }  

    public String View() {

        return "/pages/menu/menuPrincipal?faces-redirect=true";
    }

}
```

i´m using dbvisualizer because the database is of other software and i don´t understand every table.
 [image]

PKTABLE_NAME EMPRESAS LDIARIO2014
PKCOLUMN_NAME CLAVE CLAVE
FK_NAME  INTEG_651
PK_NAME   INTEG_39

**UPDATE 2** I added two new images. I think the mistake is as you say in empresa_id but I know I have to write there.

[image]
[image]

**LDiarioBean**

```
@ManagedBean(name="ldiarioBean")
@ViewScoped
@Named
public class LDiarioBean {


    private LDiario ldiario;
    @Inject
    private LDiarioService ldiarioservice;

    private LDiario selectedLdiario;

    public LDiarioService getLdiarioservice() {
        return ldiarioservice;
    }
    public void setLDiarioservice(LDiarioService ldiarioservice) {
        this.ldiarioservice = ldiarioservice;
    }


    public LDiarioBean(){

    }
    public LDiario getLdiario() {
        return ldiario;
    }
    public void setLdiario(LDiario ldiario) {
        this.ldiario = ldiario;
    } 
    public LDiario getSelectedLdiario() {
        return selectedLdiario;
    }
    public void setSelectedLdiario(LDiario selectedLdiario) {
        this.selectedLdiario = selectedLdiario;
    }    

public List<LDiario> getLDiarioList(){

        return ldiarioservice.getAll();
    }

    public LDiario getLDiario() {
        return ldiario;
    }
    public void setLDiario(LDiario ldiario) {
        this.ldiario = ldiario;
    } 
}
```

**LDiarioDAOImpl**

```
@Transactional
@Named
public class LDiarioDaoImpl implements LDiarioDao{

    @Inject
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<LDiario> findAll() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from LDiario").list();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "empresa")
private List<LDiario> ldiarios;
```

Comment: I tried a few days ago but I have another problem with LDIARIO and I think I can not bring all data at the same time because I think the table is dynamic. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Your mappings are wrong, use this

```
// Empresa.java

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "empresa")
private List<LDiario> ldiarios;


// LDiario.java

@ManyToOne  
@JoinColumn (name = "empresa_id") 
private Empresa empresa;
```

`empresa_id` is the name of the column in table `LDIARIO2014` which is a foreign key to table `empresas`.

I don't know if this is the only error you have, but it's certainly the first one that needs to be corrected. With this corrected, you should get the `ldiarios` data when you get `empresa` from DB, but weather it will show up on page depends on some more code you didn't provide (like `empresaBean`).

Anyway, try this and let us know the result.

**UPDATE 1**

First, you need to check if you are getting `ldiarios` from the database. So debug your code and see if `empresaService.getAll()` returns empresas with ldiarios (I don't see a `empresa_id` in `LDIARIO2014`, is some other column a foreign key? not clear from image).

Are those two `<p:dataTable>`s on the same page? And when you select a `empresa` in first table, you want to see the `ldiarios` in the second? If yes, change empresa view table to something like this

```
<p:dataTable id="radioDT"  var="emp" value="#{empresaBean.getEmpresaList()}"  
            selection="#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa}" rowKey="#{emp.CLAVE}">

        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{empresaBean.selectEmpresa}"
                update="tLDiarios"/>
```

Change second table to

```
<p:dataTable id="tLDiarios" var="ld" value="#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa.ldiarios}" rowKey="#{ld.CLAVE}">
```

Add this to `empresaBean`

```
public void selectEmpresa(SelectEvent event) {
    selectedEmpresa = (Empresa) event.getObject();
}
```

Comment: I added the changes but I have the same error , I added empresaBean and DbVisualizer thx you .

Comment: Ok, I added two new images. I think the mistake is as you say in empresa_id but I know I have to write there. :(

Comment: You'll have to check for yourself, or ask a DBA if you have one, if there is a foreign key between these tables, and what is it. There is a lot of problems here that need to be corrected, this can't be solved in comments. Consider splitting the whole problem into separate parts/questions. First, your db and entities need to be straightened, my answer should help there. After you know that works, then move on to displaying the data.

Comment: In this moment i´m searching foreign key betwen two tables, but i think that is each year change your name. I´ll write other post by this question, Thankyou very much.

Comment: You're welcome, hope you'll get it working at the end.